# How to do integer arithmetic in Makefile prerequisites?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a file `<n>.x` and `<n-1>.y` and I want to create a dependency in my Makefile.
Manually I can write each case as follows:

```
2.x : 1.y
3.x : 2.y
4.x : 3.y
...
```

Now I would like to be able to write this more generically:

```
%.x : <???>.y
```

Gnu Make doesn't seem to have integer arithmetic on its own and shell expansions (`$$(( ))`, `$(shell )` don't seem to work for prerequisites.

Is there a way do this in the Makefile itself or should I use an external script that can generate these dependencies and let the Makefile include them?

Edit: My specific case is dealing with files containing financial transactions. Each file (e.g. `2023.journal`) represents transactions for a specific year and includes an opening statement (e.g. `2023_opening.journal`), which is based on the closing statement of the year before that. This create a dependency between `2023_opening.journal` and `2022.journal`.

Comment: In GNU `make` (but not other `make` implementations), you could probably leverage a `.SECONDEXPANSION` to generate the wanted prerequisite name for each target name.  But this whole idea has bad code smell, and I suspect an X-Y problem.  If you give us a broader view of what you're trying to accomplish then we may be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: I've added some context that hopefully makes clear what I'm trying to accomplish. Can you tell me why this is a bad code smell?

Comment: It has bad code smell because it is conventional for the relationships between targets and prerequisites to be conveyed by filename extensions, not filename stems.  Your additional information does clarify where the idea came from, and it also informs a better approach: write a *bona fide* shell script.  Although you can probably persuade (GNU) `make` to do it, the job does not seem well suited for `make`.

Comment: Do you mean that the shell script should generate the dependencies and `make` should still perform the action of creating `2023_opening.journal` from `2022.journal` or that the shell script should do both?

Comment: I mean write a script that does the the whole job, leaving `make` out of the picture.

Comment: I am mentally too lazy to think about `.SECONDEXPANSION` and would therefore go a different route: Have one or more `Makefile` recipes generate and update one or more files to be `-include`-ed into the `Makefile`. The included file(s) would then explicitly list number specific dependencies, similar to https://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: With GNU make use secondary expansion, it is simple, clean and easy to maintain. What it changes is that the list of prerequisites can use and process automatic variables, which is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU make:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.x: $$(shell expr $$* + 1).y
```

All rules after the `.SECONDEXPANSION` special target have their list of prerequisites (and only that) processed twice by make: a first time, as everything else, when make parses the Makefile, plus a second time when make needs to check the prerequisites of a target. Contrary to the first phase, during the second phase the automatic variables are defined.

So, after the first phase the rule becomes:

```
%.x: $(shell expr $* + 1).y
```

`$*` is the make automatic variable that expands as the stem in pattern rules. In your case it is the part that matches the `%`.

And then, when make needs the list of prerequisites for `1.x`, the rule is processed again, `$(shell expr $* + 1).y` is expanded, and becomes (step by step):

1. `1.x: $(shell expr 1 + 1).y # $* --> 1`
2. `1.x: 2.y                   # $(shell expr 1 + 1) --> 2`